How do I change the width of my text to be different than the width occupied by headers and footers?
I have tried to change the margins AND textwidth using the geometry package but it seems as though you cannot use the two together. I am using XeLaTeX on overleaf.
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{datetime}

\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

% Set page size and margins
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
includefoot,
includehead,
margin=0.05\paperwidth,
width=0.6\paperwidth,
% If we remove margin settings -> textwidth adjusts
% but cannot set both margin and textwidth
headheight=23pt,
headsep = 27pt,
footskip = 50pt
}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy} % Insert Headers and Footers
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagenumbering{arabic} % Start Page numbering from 1

% Format headers and footers for document
\fancyhead[R]{\today}
\fancyhead[L]{Report title here}

\fancyfoot[L]{
    \includegraphics[height=0.03\paperwidth]{example-image-a}
}
\fancyfoot[R]{
    \thepage
}

\newpage

\section*{\label{sec: 1} A Section}

Enter content for \cref{sec: 1} here.

Here is an \textit{\textbf{unnumbered}} equation:

\[
x = y + 1.
\]

Here is a \textit{numbered} equation:

\begin{equation} \label{eq: 1}
    x^2 + y^2 = 25,
\end{equation}

To jump to the equation, click $\rightarrow$ \cref{eq: 1}.

\section*{\label{sec: 2} Another Section}
Enter content for \cref{sec: 2} here.

Here is \cref{tab: 1}:

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        Column 1 & Column 2 \\ \hline 
        1 & 2 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption here.}
    \label{tab: 1}
\end{table}

\subsection*{\label{sec: 2.1} A Subsection}
Content for \cref{sec: 2.1} here.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption here.}
    \label{fig: 1}
\end{figure}

To jump to figure, click \cref{fig: 1}.

\end{document}

Actual Output:

Desired Output (text width smaller than that set by margins):


As always here, please provide a full but minimal example others can copy and work with. We have no idea which class etc you are using and the answer depends on this information.

That is not a minimal exmaple. You haven't given us something we can copy and test as is, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228

I have included a MWE now, apologies and thank you for pointing me to the right resources.

Unrelated but note that \section*{\label{foo} baz} is (1) pointless because starred sections have no number which can be referred to, and (2) introducing a spurious space before the section title.

You can use \fancyheadoffset{...} and \fancyfootoffset{...} to make the header and footer wider than your text:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{datetime}

\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

% Set page size and margins
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
includefoot,
includehead,
margin=0.15\paperwidth,
%width=0.6\paperwidth,
% If we remove margin settings -> textwidth adjusts
% but cannot set both margin and textwidth
headheight=23pt,
headsep = 27pt,
footskip = 50pt
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy} % Insert Headers and Footers
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagenumbering{arabic} % Start Page numbering from 1

\fancyheadoffset{2cm}
\fancyfootoffset{2cm}

% Format headers and footers for document
\fancyhead[R]{\today}
\fancyhead[L]{Report title here}

\fancyfoot[L]{
    \includegraphics[height=0.03\paperwidth]{example-image-a}
}
\fancyfoot[R]{
    \thepage
}

\lipsum
\end{document}



Very helpful command, thank you for this. Will need to adjust some parameters slightly but exactly what i needed!

@ZainSiddiqi You're welcome!
